# I want to attach oled 1.3" to nodemcu esp32s

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-ide, lcd, arduino-esp32

I want to attach oled 1.3" SH1106 to nodemcu esp32s I used this library (https://github.com/wonho-maker/Adafruit_SH1106) but it says "adafruit_sh1106.cpp:29:26: fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: no such file or directory". I tried to use another library (https://github.com/nhatuan84/esp32-sh1106-oled) and it uploaded successfully but it doesn't show anything.

P.N:my nodemcu esp32s's scl and sda pins are 22 and 21

Answer (score 0):

The message about `avr/pgmspace.h` means that the library isn't compatible with the ESP32. That's a file that only exists on Arduino CPUs; it's not part of the ESP32's software. If you want to use this library you'll need to figure out for yourself how to make it compatible with the ESP32, which may be a lot of work.

If you want to find out why the other library doesn't work you'll need to post a new question and include your program (cut down to be a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates the problem) and precise, complete details on how you wired the display to the ESP32.